# Omitting subdirectories when import custom modules python

Tags: python, python-import

```
crispy13/
    __init__.py
    core/
        __init__.py
        ecf.py
```

How can i load the ecf module in the following ways?

```
from crispy13 import ecf
OR
from crispy13.ecf import *
```

instead of 
`from crispy13.core.ecf import *`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[like sahasrara62 said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60594552/7865368) it can be done in the following manner
in `crispy13/__init__.py` import your module as

```
from .core import ecf
```

you can also make use of `__all__` variable in your `__init__.py` file.
This is a very good way of importing modules/functions/classes.
**Little bit insight to why we do imports in this way.**
 Let's suppose you are using a third-party
 library/package and there are some implementation changes in the module

1. changes the place of the function/class that you are importing
2. removed a module and put its contents into another module of the same package

then your import will break.

 That's why all third party libraries/packages include all of their consumable functions/classes/modules
    in the root `__init__.py`  file of their package.

Comment: using `__all__` is not advisable, as it require maintenance of code base,  improper maintenance affect the project

Comment: @sahasrara62 only if you're not maintaining the code.

Comment: just doont use it, it is bad practice

Comment: checkout these modules: re, logging, json, base64 and I'm sure there are more. It's not a bad practice.

Comment: In my case, how could i edit `__all__` variable? `__all__ = [ '.core.ecf' ]`?

Comment: @Crispy13 you need to first import it in your `__init__.py` file and then put it in `__all__` variable(`list`).

Comment: Then, adding `from .core import ecf` and `__all__=['ecf']` is correct?

Comment: @Crispy13 it's correct. But remember `__all__` is only useful when you are doing `*` import.

Answer (score 1):

in `crispy13/__init__.py` import the package as

`from .core import ecf`